# Power Bi vs Power Query group by

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Help!
I own a huge database containing millions of rows of transactions. It does contain many columns with diverse information :
[image: Analytic table sample]

I am working on a power bi dashboard resuming such information, so, to reduce my input base for, I was using the "group by" on the power query, so, I am grouping such table by (command created by point and click options of power query) :

```
{"STATUS", "PRODUTO", "PARCEIRO", "MARCA", "data_transação"}, {{"Agg_Valor_Transação", each List.Sum([Valor_Transação]), type nullable number}, {"Agg_Receita", each List.Sum([RECEITA]), type nullable number}, {"Agg_Cashback", each List.Sum([CASHBACK]), type nullable number}})
```

It does work in power query as you can see below
[image: Power query group by result example]

But as long as a close power query, the same table in power by shows me this values!

[image: same table loaded in power bi]

And bigger! every time I edit the query and open it in power by the results are increased!

obs : Such table currently does not contain any relationship defined in the model

Comment: Difficult to understand the case with this explanation. I would suggest you try with a small table with similar data. If you see your steps still generating the issue, it will be easy for you to fix. Hope you are applying the changes by click on the button "Close and Apply" after your edit.